# how do i add new property to existing interface and then export the new interface in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface, ecmascript-2016

How do I create and export a new interface - UIInterface: (would like to combine SummaryInterface with few other new properties)

Example:

```
import { SummaryInterface } from 'x-api'; // summaryInterface has 20+ properties defined and is auto-generated from script
```

My attempt

```
export interface UIInterface {
    SummaryInterface &
     { displayStatus: string;
       flag: boolean }; 
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking to [extend an interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces) like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/exporting-extended-interface-xux37)?  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, can you elaborate?  It would be nice to see a [mcve] here (so a definition of `SummaryInterface` along with some code that shows use cases).

Comment: Is extending interface similar to combining properties of the super interface with other self-defined properties?

Comment: Yes:  From the handbook "This allows you to copy the members of one interface into another, which gives you more flexibility in how you separate your interfaces into reusable components"

Comment: . I think extending the interface works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By extending the other interface like so:

```js
export interface UIInterface extends SummaryInterface {
  displayStatus: string;
  flag: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code :

**By extending the parent class property**

Explanation : Basically, your in below code, have both the properties of your parent and child interface.

```
export interface UIInterface extends SummaryInterface {
  displayStatus: string;
  flag: boolean;
}
```